# Checking the existence of a kafka topic in Faust app

Tags: python, apache-kafka, faust

I am new to Faust.

Task in hand is to make sure a few Kafka topics exist. Idea is to check if all the required topics exist in app's liveliness check.

I have gone through Faust documentation but didn't find a way to do that. Is it even possible to do that in Faust application?

Can we use native Kafka list topics (http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listTopics--) in Faust?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use native Kafka list topics in Faust

Assuming you have Java installed where Faust is running, you could run a shell command, sure.

Otherwise, you can use `kafka-python` or `confluent-kafka-python` AdminClient's to check for topic existence